# Modification on USB bootable drive

Tags: 11.04, usb, usb-drive, live-usb

A USB bootable drive discards all modifications made at shutdown. Is there a way to save it? If possible, how will that affect a version installed on to a different hard disk using that USB drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How to make a dedicated Unity USB Stick**

- This is a way to make a USB key with
  Ubuntu prereleases installed on it
  that you can update every day and not
  have to break your existing install.

**Step 1: Download the latest Daily Natty image**

- Go to [this page](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/natty/release/) and download an ISO
  for your computer. It should be saved
  to the Downloads directory on your
  computer.

**Step 2: Create the USB stick installation**

- Click System -> Administration ->
  Startup Disk Creator. It looks like
  this:
  [image: SDC]

When you start the application, it will likely automatically find the ISO you downloaded, which is displayed in the top pane. If you don’t see it, click the Other button and go and select the ISO (typically in your Downloads/ directory in your home directory).

It is recommended you first erase your USB stick, so select it in the bottom pane and click the Erase Disk button. When this is complete, you can then use the *slider underneath the Stored in reserved extra space slider to select how much disk space can be used for saving files, documents and other things*. Depending on the size of your USB move the slider all the way to the right to use the maximum space available.

Finally, click the Make Startup Disk button and Natty will be installed to your USB stick.

**Step 3: Boot into the Key**

- Now you need to boot from USB stick.
  To do this you may need to enter your
  BIOS to enable your computer to be
  able to boot from the USB stick. When
  this is enabled you will typically
  need to hit a button when you boot to
  see the BIOS’s boot menu  and then you
  can select the USB drive.

  Ubuntu should boot and look and
  function the same as usual, apart
  from being much slower as you are
  running from the USB disk.

**Step 4: Update and Prepare the Key**

- Although you installed the latest
  daily you should ensure it is up to
  date, and you can do this with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```
- From now on you can update the key
  daily to keep it up to date. Now you
  need to enable apport so that when
  something crashes it can report it to
  Launchpad:

  Edit /etc/default/apport, set and set
  enabled=1.

**Step 5: Test and Report Bugs**

- If we don’t know about the bugs
  our community can’t fix them!
- Since the key can be updated you
  merely need to update it before you
  are ready to test and then try it on
  as many pieces of hardware that you
  can find. Since apport is set to
  report crashers you can quickly start
  finding hardware bugs.
- Filing a bug
  is simple. Just open a terminal and
  run:

  ```
  ubuntu-bug unity
  ```
- The ubuntu-bug program zips up some
  debugging data from your system and
  will then fire up a page in your
  browser where you can enter a bug
  report. This will then provide
  details of the problem to the Unity
  developers to help fix the bug.

[**Ubuntu Liveusb Wiki**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/InstallUSBKey)

Comment: Count on !GB of persistent storage for proprietary drivers + updates.

Answer (score 0):

I would caution against doing an update or upgrade on a persistent usb drive.

Maximum persistence size is 4GB and this can quickly be fill doing updates.

Upgrades are not possible as the kernel is located in filesystem.squashfs which is read only.

Once the casper-rw file is filled, the drive will not boot,

In this case the casper-rw file may be mounted and data removed from it.

Casper-rw partitions can be used for persistence size over 4GB.

Comment: Just remove the apt cache to keep that from happening