# How can I fix a "disk not ready error" when booting from USB?

Tags: installation, boot, usb

I installed Ubuntu and everything went ok. I did it by looking at this guide

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/23/install-ubuntu-11-04-on-external-hard-disk/

Then when it boots from USB I get this error at the begining while booting

`disk drive for boot is not ready yet or not present`

According to [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) method 1 I went to `grub/grub.cfg` (since in GRUB 2 its no more menu.lst) and changed all `/dev/sdc` to `/dev/sda` as the guy says in his guide, but after these changes it still gives me the same error message. Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Don't complicate yourself : http://askubuntu.com/questions/43786/modification-on-usb-bootable-drive/43788#43788

Comment: This one too, take a look at my answer  : http://askubuntu.com/questions/46624/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-with-multiple-iso-images-in-it/46634#46634

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using /dev/anything in grub.cfg or /etc/fstab because device references are subject to change.  Instead you should be using the UUID.